# How to solve this multivariable limit?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

I want to know if that function is continuous at $(0,0)$. So I tried to evaluate the limit at this point but I don't know how to solve it.
\begin{equation}
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \left(\frac{x\sqrt{y}}{x^4+y^2}\right)
\end{equation}
Thanks in advance

Comment: What techniques do you know for solving limits? What have you tried?

Comment: I tried with polar coordinates, but I don't know if that's the best way to face the limit.

Comment: Please, make sure to write mathematical expressions in LaTeX next time. I formatted it for you this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Try the two paths $y=x\to 0$ and $y=0,x\to 0$ to show that the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your function is defined by cases, otherwise asking if it is continuos in a point where it's not even defined would be meaningless.
A function $f:A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow R$ is continuos if and only if it's sequentially continuos, that means:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=f(x_0)\iff\forall\{x_n\}\subseteq A: x_n\rightarrow x_0 \implies f(x_n)\rightarrow f(x_0) \tag{1}
\end{equation}
Consider the sequence $\{(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n^2})\}_{n\geqslant1}$ that converges to $(0,0)$. If you compute:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to +\infty}f(x_n)=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{n^4}+\frac{1}{n^4}}=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{n^2}}{\frac{1}{n^4}}=\lim_{n\to +\infty} n^2=+\infty
\tag{2}
\end{equation}
If your function were continuos at $(0,0)$, you would have that:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=f(x_0)
\end{equation}
that, considering $(1)$ is clearly in contradiction with $(2)$.